# react-router v6 how to get active subroute

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Is there a way to get the current (active) sub-route without using `state`?

For example, there is:

```
    <Route path="home/*" element={<Home />}>
         <Route index element={<Main />} />
         <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
    </Route>
```

I would like to have a hook that I would use inside `Home` like this:

```
    const Home = () =>
         useMyHook().activeSubPath === "about" ? (
             <>
                 <h1>We are at about page</h1>
                 <Outlet />
             </>
         ) : (
             <Outlet />
         );
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a nav bar and highlight the active page ?

Comment: @MridulGupta Are you hinting at NavLink?:) I need more global hook)

Comment: Yeah @АндрейГригорьев NavLink is what I'm thinking of, can you elaborate more as into what you need the hook for?

Comment: Why not to use useLocation or even useMatch?

Comment: @MridulGupta i wanna show/hide a banner on different pages

Comment: @AndreySmolko useLocation and useMatch requires more hardcode for urls, i can use it, but it is interesting, is there any more beautiful solutions